# Accessing Value in Vector->List->(Node *)->name

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm implementing Adjacency List and I've a `struct Node` which have a `string name` variable that I want to access/print.

I'm writing this code in `main function`:

```
vector  <list<Node*>> mylist(NP);

vector  <list<Node*>>::iterator itr = mylist.begin();
int i=0;
while(i<NP)
{
    Node *temp = new Node();
    fin>>temp->name;
    itr->push_back(temp);

    itr++;
    i++;
}

itr = mylist.begin();
list<Node*>::iterator itr2 = itr->begin();
cout<<itr2->name;
```

but last line is not working for me. what should I do?

Comment: What do you expect `list<Node*>::iterator itr2 = itr->begin();` to accomplish?

Comment: Nevermind, I'm drunk.

Comment: LOL it's okay. and through that line I want to access the first Node of the first `list` of `mylist` vector. :P

Comment: _"is not working for me"_ Right um okay what does that mean? What SPECIFICALLY happens? Or are we to magically guess?

Comment: Yeah magically! :P Because In magicians language `cout<<` means to print out what is given to it but in simple language "is not working for me" means not giving the output (programmetically it means giving error) ;) but now it's working by the given solution below. So chill boy! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the last line could be:

```
vector  <list<Node*>> mylist(NP);

vector  <list<Node*>>::iterator itr = mylist.begin();
int i=0;
while(i<NP)
{
    Node *temp = new Node();
    fin>>temp->name;
    itr->push_back(temp);

    itr++;
    i++;
}
itr = mylist.begin();
list<Node*>::iterator itr2 = itr->begin();
cout<<(*itr2)->name.c_str();
```

Comment: using `c_str()` function is redundant. std::string knows how to `<<` itself

Answer (score 0):

`itr2` is an iterator of container of `Node*`s. In order to get a field in `Node`, you should first dereference `itr2`,  and get the `Node*` object, then you can use the `->` operator and get the field. So that line should work :
`cout << (*itr2)->name`